# How to set up multisite in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am not familiar with how to set up multisite in WordPress in which I can create multisite in one WordPress installation. I need help, please step by step explain me how to do that?

Comment: Did you get check the link?

Comment: Thanks Again I Got It

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yashpal Modi,

It is long process if you are technical person than please add below code to your wp-config.php and than check your admin panel you will get the network section form where you can create multisites.

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

If you are non technical or you are facing some issue for further process.

Please check this [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/multisite/) and follow the steps it is very simple and easy. let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rules of creating multi site,

rule 1: 
Under the line where it says  "That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging. "
add the following code:
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

rule 2:Go to admin panel,Tools > Network Setup
Then read the instruction for htaccess page and wp-config.php page
 Then follow the instruction

Now your website is multi site website.You can easily create any sub domain site.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not deeply familiar with WordPress settings, that might be a better option to go with a pre-configured package that already includes multisite setup. This can be a [cluster](https://jelastic.com/blog/wordpress-hosting-enterprise-high-availability-auto-scaling/) or [standalone](https://jelastic.com/blog/wordpress-hosting-standalone-container/) package.

After installation, multisite mode is automatically enabled and the websites can be created in one of the following ways within a single network:

- **sub-domains** — a domain-based network in which on-demand sites use subdomains
- **sub-folders** — a path-based network in which on-demand sites use paths

In the article [WordPress Multisite Network with Domain Mapping and CDN](https://jelastic.com/blog/wordpress-multisite-network/), you can find out how to create several websites, bind custom domains, issue SSL certificates and integrate CDN in a few minutes using a single WordPress installation.